# Reverting Windows 8.1 project to Windows 8.0

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

A very simple question. I re-targeted my whole project to Windows 8.1 couple of months ago.

Now I need to publish the latest version of my project for Windows 8.0 Store too, but I need to re-target the project back to Windows 8.0 since Windows 8.0 users can't use my Windows 8.1 Store version of the app.

Comment: Do you have source control?

Comment: I do have source control, but I've been updating the Windows 8.1 version on it. This means I could pull an older version for Windows 8.0, but there are many changes since then. I'm trying to avoid pulling an old version and copy/pasting all the code from the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 8.0 branch off of your source control at a point before you updated to 8.1, then merge the next checking into that branch without the changes that happened to the csproj and then merge the current version. There would be a few lines in the csproj that you would want to keep unchanged like the following changes:

ToolsVersion update:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Added properties:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

Visual Studio version update:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '12.0' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```